# Trying to implement swiper into my website code for gesture navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I wanted to implement swiper.js navigation into my website code but I am doing something wrong because its not working. I want to be able to change pages with swiping gesture when on mobile.

Steps I did:

1)$ npm install swiper

2)

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/swiper.min.css">
```

and

```js
<script src="path/to/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

3)

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <header class="main-head">
                        <img src="logo.svg" height="100%"></img>
                </header>
                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="swiper-slide">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page2.html" class="swiper-slide">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="page3.html" class="swiper-slide">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

4)

```css
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

5)

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,
```

6)

```css
.swiper-wrapper{display:grid;grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(3, 1fr));grid-template-rows:repeat(2,auto) 4fr auto;grid-column-gap:0;grid-row-gap:0;height:100vh}
```

Thank you in advance! P.S I had downloaded swiper.min.js $ swiper.min.css files into my website folder.

Comment: Can you please clarify what dosnt work ? Looks good to me, also can you add a minimal working example ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: First of all thank you on reply, swiper.js css file overrides my main-css file messing my layout and when I try swiping gesture it doesnt switch pages like in demo examples shown on their website. https://swiperjs.com/demos/